# Hi - this may be a question that was asked before but how do we assign a variable's value as Property / Value of another new variable?

Tags: javascript, object, variables, properties, this

I am trying to match 2 clicks - one from Phrasal Verb

to one from Meaning's

and combine them as 
Objects into a new variable called userSelect.

Making the Phrasal Verb

clickable to become new Property of userSelect and getting the clicked Phrasal Verb's #id:

```
$(".question").on("click", "li", (function(){
    $(this).attr("id");
    var selPhrase = $(this).attr("id");
    console.log(selPhrase);
    $(".msg1").css("opacity", "1");
}));
```

Making the Meaning

clickable to become new Value of userSelect and getting the clicked Meaning's #id:

```
$(".answer").on("click", "li", (function(){
    $(this).attr("id");
    var selMeaning = $(this).attr("id");
    console.log(selMeaning);
}));
```

Combining two above with userSelect as new variable Property  and Value for this new variable:

```
var userSelect = {};
userSelect[selPhrase]= selMeaning;
console.log(userSelect);
```

The problem is, when it is run, Chrome JS console says selPhrase (and selMeaning too) is not defined, why? Please advise me, thanks. I have already installed Babel extension inside my VS Code.

Comment: When you `console.log()` both `selPhrase` and `selMeaning`, what do you get?

Also, where are you using this
 `var userSelect = {};
userSelect[selPhrase]= selMeaning;
console.log(userSelect);`  
You may have to make `selPhrase` and `selMeaning` a global variable

Comment: Search for “javascript variable scopes”.

Comment: @Syntiara thank you for replying - when I console.log(selPhrase) and console.log(selMeaning), each one gives me a string derived from each id - one and alpha respectively. So how do I make these two variables global then? Thanks for helping me.

Comment: Hi, @DanielL sorry for the late reply. You can make them a global variable by defining above the function calls, not inside of the function